# replace a image in html with using of java script

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I don't understand what am I doing wrong here, I try to debug the code, but I did not found what I did wrong here.
I tried to replace the image in html with using of java script, I would appreciate some useful help for my problem

*Html code:*

```
<img id = "lamp" src = "js/Capture.PNG"/>    
<!--make a button to turn on or off the lamp  in this case --> 

<button id = "off" name  = "offf" onclick="change_attribute()" >Turn off the light</button>
<button id = "on" name  = "offf" onclick="change_attribute()"> turn on the light </button>
```

*Javacript code:*

```
function change_attribute() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("offf");

    if (x.id === "off")
    {
        document.getElementById('off').src = "js/Capture.PNG/";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('on').src = 'js/Capture2.PNG/'
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Not sure how C# is relevant!

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByName(`) method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name. you are trying to reference an `id` property which doesn't exist in the array but on the actual array elements.

You should propbably refactor your code to use a single html element which calls the `change_attribute()` and it will toggle the state respectively between on and off.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName()` returns an array of HTML elements that specifies the given condition.

In your condition you are getting array of buttons html element as a result of which, when you are accessing `x.id` then it is giving error as x is array, rather than object.

try to refactor your code and call `change_attribute` from one place only

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change_attribute(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "off")
    {
        document.getElementById('lamp').src = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2910/2910914.png";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('lamp').src = 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/702/702797.png'
    }
    
}
```

```css
#lamp{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin-right:15px;

}
```

```html
<img id="lamp" src ="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2910/2910914.png"/>    
<!--make a button to turn on or off the lamp  in this case --> 

<button id="off" class="lightBtn" onclick="change_attribute(event)" >Turn off the light</button>
<button id="on"  class="lightBtn" onclick="change_attribute(event)"> turn on the light </button>
```

Comment: Hi @Warrior if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.